# TypeScript: How can I catch cases where I'm missing `.bind` at compile time?

Tags: typescript

I occasionally forget to call `.bind` with a class method before passing it as an argument, e.g.

```js
const x = {
    add(n: number) { return n + 1 },
};

class Y {
    constructor(private readonly extra: number) {}
    add(n: number) { return n + this.extra }
}
const y = new Y(1);

// TypeScript doesn't report any compile-time errors, but the third call will at runtime.
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(x.add));
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(y.add.bind(y)));
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(y.add)); // Runtime error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extra')
```

Is there a way to get TypeScript or typescript-eslint to catch this kind of mistake at compile time?

Answer (score 1):

[`typescript-eslint/unbound-method`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/unbound-method/) will warn you on the first and third occurrences:

[image]

> Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of `this`.
>
> If your function does not access `this`, you can annotate it with `this: void`, or consider using an arrow function.

While `.map(x.add)` doesn't throw a runtime error, it looks quite suspicious because you're referencing `.add` without a calling context of `x`, and would be a mistake in most cases, I'd think - so warning at that point in addition to `.map(y.add)` makes sense.